# Publication rates for different areas of mathematics?

Tags: journals

Are there any numbers on publication rates for different areas of mathematics? For example, I would expect that the average in graph theory is higher than the average in analysis.

Comment: If one could interrogate MathSciNet electronically then one could look at primary MSC numbers on papers, but I don't think you can do this. Also, one might wish to filter the results to "core" mathematics journals, whatever this means, but there have been concerns the top journals are biased towards certain topics, so YMMV.

Comment: I think you will find this answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/233994/11260

Comment: Carlo, that's a start. I would like to see information about average rates. For example, is it more common for a graph theorist than an analyst to publish more than ten or more papers in 5 years? what about 15 or more papers?

Comment: You equally count a 100-page paper single-authored and a 3-page paper with 5 authors?

Answer (score 16):

I'm hesitating to give this answer, but Italy has researched the question "on average how many papers per year does a professor in a given field publish", and they have made this into a selection criterion for promotions. It's a crazy system, but here is [their table](http://abilitazione.miur.it/public/documenti/2018/Tabelle_Valori_Soglia_ALLEGATI_DM_589_2018.pdf), for what it's worth. It will tell you that in mathematical analysis or statistics the average output of a full professor (*I fascia*) is 10 papers in 10 years, while in mathematical logic it is 5 papers in 10 years.

<sub>These are among the lowest rates in the table, if you are in the medical profession the average output can be above 10 publications per year. In my own field, condensed matter physics, I might qualify as an Italian professor with less than 3 papers per year.</sub>

This "bean counting" procedure was made into a [national law,](http://abilitazione.miur.it/public/documenti/2018/DM_Valori_Soglia_589_08082018.pdf) if you can read Italian it will bring tears to your eyes.

Comment: Average is the mean or median? I would guess the mean, given the statistical ignorance this exercise shows.

Comment: Carlo, It brought both tears and laughter! Still, I would like to see similar information for schools in the US.

Comment: They are crazy, indeed!

Comment: @DavidRoberts These used to be called 'medians' (along the population of all associate/full professors) in a previous version of the procedure, and that's how they were computed (possibly wrongly, since it's difficult to gather data on the whole population). In the current version they are simply defined as 'threshold values' that one needs to achieve for habilitation to that category. I guess part of the reason for this change is that you can sue them for computing a median incorrectly, but you cannot sue them for defining an arbitrary threshold value incorrectly...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni thanks, and good point!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: "It will tell you that in mathematical analysis or statistics the average output is 1 paper a year, twice that in mathematical logic." is ambiguous to me. Does it expand to "it is twice that in mathematical logic" or "which is twice that [the rate] in mathematical logic"?

Comment: @JW Ooh thanks I misread that, it makes sense this way indeed. Anyway, I have deleted that comment and made an edit to the answer in the hope to make this clearer.

Comment: Soon there will be many people in Italy working in mathematical logic. Particularly computer scientists will change fields.

Comment: @DanFox --- true, also notice that professors of computer science are expected to accumulate nearly 100 times as many citations to their papers as those working in mathematical logic! The sad thing is that this crazy system is taken very seriously. At one point I received a request if I could please cite one particular paper, even if totally out of context, just to tip the scale for a promotion in Italy. (The Hirsch index works that way, one fine tuned citation out of several hundreds can make the difference between promotion or no promotion.)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Unfortunately this same disease has taken root in Spain. To *apply* for university jobs one must be acredited by a national agency; the criteria specify imprecise area dependent threshholds based on certain numbers of papers in journals with certain impact factors. This perturbs the behavior of researchers (young and old) in easily anticipated and largely negative (from the point of view of production of interesting research) ways.

Comment: So if in 10 years you publish 4 papers in logic, 7 papers in Algebra, 9 papers in analysis, 12 papers in numerical analysis and 40 papers in experimental physics you will not be a suitable candidate for anything. Join the workforce!